# Hive doesn't respond when I try to make a query

Tags: amazon-ec2, hadoop, hive

I have a setup on a EC2 instance that uses Whirr to spin up new hadoop instances. I have been trying to get Hive to work with this setup. Hive should be configured to use mysql as the local metastore. The issue that I am having is that every time I try to run a query like( CREATE TABLE testers (foo INT, bark STRING);  ) via the hive interface it just hangs there and doesn't seem like it is doing anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would first get the debug output from the hive command line to see where it is hanging. Run the hive shell with this parameter, and then paste the output of your command.

hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console

Comment: For me it's `Starting Job = job_1429391358007_0387, Tracking URL = http://node1:8088/proxy/application_1429391358007_0387/
INFO exec.Task: Starting Job = job_1429391358007_0387, Tracking URL = http://node1:8088/proxy/application_1429391358007_0387/
Kill Command = /opt/mapr/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1429391358007_0387` and then just continuous heartbeating: `DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (397816573) connection to node1/192.168.200.161:8032 from mapr sending #11; DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (397816573) connection to node1/192.168.200.161:8032 from mapr got value #11`


What does it tell me?